# objective-c/iOS Track location with camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps

I want to display real time video on the iPhone Screen.
I know the GPS coordinate of my house.

I want to display a vertical line on the screen that shows me my house direction.
If i move my phone, turn left, right, i want the vertical line to move left and right to show where is my house.

If my house is behind me, i do not want to see the vertical line.

Do you think this kind of application is easy to make ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011083

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use "Augmented Reality". You can find many more source code for this. 
Please check the below links:

[Location Based AR](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42266/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based)

[Augmented Reality Toolkit](https://github.com/a1phanumeric/iPhone-AR-Toolkit)